# Measure how long a rendered frame takes to arrive on a client from the cloud

Tags: gpu

Say I am running a game in the cloud and I am playing that game on my client (the game is being streamed from the cloud to the client), be it a laptop, phone or calculator.

How can I work out how long a frame (of the game being played) takes to arrive at the client?

Comment: This seems to have a couple of problems. a) It's not entirely clear whether you're the developer or just a player of the game (in the latter case, this is clearly off-topic, as this site is about computer graphics *programming* and *research*). b) If you are the developer this doesn't seem to be actually about graphics but more about the network code of your game. In that case, you might want to try [GameDev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or [so] but be sure to read their respective help centres to make sure your question is of high-quality and on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a timestamp over some key frames as the last step on your render pipeline. Then compare it to the local systems time. If both clocks are correct you should get a delay in ms (using unix rime-stamps).

Another idea to measure the round-trip-delay (might be important for UX reasons):
input to server,
server render,
result from to server on your screen
is to have a bot give an input than measure the time till the result is back

Comment: How would I go about accessing the key frames? I'm not really sure where to start. The game would be streamed from the cloud to a client. Thanks

Comment: maybe try to record it and than search them by hand. I know this is far away from any kind of automated test or even realtime feedback, but it seemed to be the rather uncomplicated